# Importing ontology from Protege to Sesame

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege, sesame

I have created an ontology where I've imported a couple of external ontologies and mapped some of my classes to those in them. When I open the ontology in Protege, I see the classes that I created as well as the mapping to other ontologies.

However, when I open the ontology in a text editor or export it to Sesame, I only see the classes I created or mapped to those in existing ontologies. The ones I haven't touched do not show up. I need all the classes from the imported ontologies for my application. How do I get them to show up in my owl file?

UPDATE1

When I import these ontologies directly into Sesame, all the triples show up. This is in contrast to the case of importing these ontologies to Protege and then uploading the file to Sesame. In the latter case, the classes I haven't modified/mapped to those in my ontology don't show up.

What explains the difference in the behavior?

These are the ontologies I am concerned with:

1. http://svn.code.sf.net/p/vaccineontology/code/trunk/src/ontology/VO.owl
2. http://ovae.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/ontology/ovae.owl

Comment: Are you asking how to view/explore/edit/(whatever) your imported ontologies in Protege? If so: what does Sesame have to do with this?

Comment: Updated the questions to clarify the problem. Hope it adds the requisite context.